# DateTime TryParse problem

Tags: c#

```
string date = txtWorkingDate.Text;
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.MinValue;

            if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out dateTime))
            {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }
            else
                args.IsValid = false;
```

txtWorkingDate.Text is like "dd.MM.yyyy" becouse of this validateion is always false if date is not like "dd.MM.yyyy". How c an i check types of date like "dd.MM.yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy" becouse are all valid.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx) and providing the accepted formats:

```
string date = txtWorkingDate.Text;
DateTime dateTime;
string[] formats = new[] { "dd.MM.yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy" };
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
{
    args.IsValid = true;
}
else
{
    args.IsValid = false;
}
```

Comment: It always returns false no matter the format I enter the date :(

Comment: @Axel try to add to the formats all the possbile combination. I mean..

dd.MM.yyyy, d.MM.yyyy, dd.M.yyyy and so on

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureinfo =  
        new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-gb"); 
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("13/12/2009", cultureinfo);
```

You need to specify the culture assuming you know it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the

```
DateTime.TryParse(
    string s,
    IFormatProvider provider,
    DateTimeStyles styles,
    out DateTime result
)
```

overload.

Also, you don't need the if, you can simply write

```
args.IsValid = DateTime.TryParse(...);
```

As `DateTime.TryParse()` already returns a bool.